# How to enable public IP access in Vertex Colab Enterprise notebook?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

When creating a new runtime template, the public internet access option is greyed out (restricted by organization policies).

I have tried the following organization policies:
Restrict environment options on new Vertex AI Workbench notebooks and instances
Restrict public IP access on new Vertex AI Workbench notebooks and instances
Restrict VPC networks on new Vertex AI Workbench instances

So far, I am still blocked here. What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: did you try this one? Define allowed external IPs for VM instances